# How do they make bold-type letters in comments?

Tags: support, comments

How do they make letters in bold in comments? I see bold type in comments every now and then. It's very useful, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question on the meta Meta:

[Text formatting now allowed in comments (List of proven and disproven abilities)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities)

To summarize, `**this is bold**` and `*this is italic*`. `*You can also do **bold italic** but only in the middle of bold or italic text*`.

Comment: @brilliant: You can also use `_this_` and `__this__` to obtain respectively _italic_ and __bold__.

Comment: Another thing: There's an orange (or yellowish) question mark on the right side of the toolbar above text areas for entering answers and questions, and the question mark links to a page explaining markdown formatting options. As was noted, not all markdown options work in comments, just some.

Answer (score 2):

As you're typing a comment, there is a button marked *help* beside the comment box. It will tell you everything you need to know.